# Read only query, need to close the connection. Rollback, commit or leave 'as is'?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, database-performance

I have done a read only query, now it is time to close the connection.

Assuming this is a frequent query, and I cannot easily just keep the connection open, it is better for performance to commit, to rollback or just call close() without doing anything else?

It is Oracle database, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is read-only, then there is nothing to commit or to rollback. You just close the connection.